# iOS accessory compatible app list

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

Hivemind, a drone needs assistance!

I have a Bluetooth accessory (a RFID stick reader) and, once paired, iOS would inform me that I do not have the app that the accessory uses installed and present a link to the aforementioned app on the App Store.

My app uses the accessory and is indeed fully compatible, is there any way I could embed my app into the list of supported apps for this particular accessory? My guess is that the app is defined by the accessory owner/manufacturer, but still, it would be huge discovery for my app if I could do this.

Comment: It sounds like the peripheral is MFi certified. You need to add the external accessory identifier to your apps info.plist and I believe you will require the hardware vendor to add your app bundle Id to their MFi agreement with Apple in order for your app to be approved

Comment: It is indeed MFI certified. The identifier's already in the app's .plist as that's a requirement in interacting with the peripheral. Yeah, that makes sense, will see if I can do anything 'bout that. Thanks for the suggestion! :)